# dynamic variable in cakephp find queries

Tags: php, cakephp, php-5.5, cakephp-2.5

I have a query like this in a CakePHP application

```
            // Check for txn_id
            $txns = $this->$transaction_class->find('count', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    $transaction_class.'.txn' => $txnId 
                )   
            ));
```

As you can see, my variable **transaction_class** is a dynamic variable. Form some reason this does not work. I even tried to put the variables inside **{}** like:

```
            // Check for txn_id
            $txns = $this->{$transaction_class}->find('count', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    $transaction_class.'.txn' => $txnId 
                )   
            ));
```

But that didn't work either. Does anybody know how I can make this work please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check your model is imported on this page or not or added in **$uses** array.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to load my model